# How to share FactoryGirl in a GEM with my Ruby project?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, factory-bot

I have moved models to a separate GEM so I can reuse it in different projects.

I named the gem `core` and it looks something like:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── db
├── lib
│   ├── plum
│   │   ├── core
│   │   ├── core.rb
│   │   └── logging.rb
│   └── plum.rb
├── pkg
├── core.gemspec
├── spec
│   ├── factories
│   │   ├── access_tokens.rb
│   │   └── users.rb
│   ├── fixtures
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── integration
│   │   └── user_spec.rb
│   ├── spec_helper.rb
│   ├── support│   │ 
│   ├── switch_test.rb
│   └── unit
│       ├── access_tokens_spec.rb
│       └── users_spec.rb
└── tasks
```

Now I created an API using Grape and I included the models by adding the gem to my Gemfile and everything is working fine.

My main problem is that now I want to share `Factories` between the two projects so I can write some requests tests in my API project.

In my Grape project in `spec_helper.rb` I have something like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'factory_girl'

ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require 'rack/test'

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require 'core'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.expect_with :rspec
  config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end

require 'capybara/rspec'
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.app = Plum::App.new
  config.server_port = 9293
end
```

But seems I can't include the gem in my rspec_helper somehow. As I'm getting this :

```
/Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- core (LoadError)
```

I'm including the gem to my API by adding `gem 'core', git: 'https://some_url.git', branch: 'develop'`

and it's working fine as I can access the models already.

Comment: Your gem's `lib` folder will be added to the path, so you probably need to `require 'plum/core'` instead of `require 'core'` - I am not sure what the "plum.rb" and "plum" directory are there for in your project? It is more conventional to place a .rb file named after your gem directly in the lib folder.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for your willing to help. Please note that the tests not at lib folder as you can see. Aw tried your workaround and it didn't work out => /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- plum/core (LoadError)

Comment: How are you invoking the test?

Comment: I'm invoking it with `bundle exec rspec .` . Please note that I'm including the gem in the API using  gem 'core', git: 'https://some_url.git', branch: 'develop' and it's working fine but i'm still confused why i can require the gem in my tests.

Comment: The gem line you quoted adds stuff to your path but doesn't `require` anything. So something is successfully loading the model definitions. What is the `require` statement in the main Grape app that gives you access to the model? Is it possible you have code from before your split into a gem active somewhere, so you aren't loading the files that you think you are?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got this right. At the moment I only include the gem in Gemfile for the API. in boot.rb i have something like `require 'rubygems'; require 'bundler/setup'` then I can use any of the models something like `App::Core::User`

Comment: Those lines don't actually load your gems. Do you have something like `Bundler.require(:default)` too?

Comment: @NeilSlater yes the first few lines of my `spec_helper` `require 'rubygems'
;require 'bundler/setup' ; Bundler.require(:default, :development)`.

Comment: @NeilSlater now I'm getting this error: ` Failure/Error: user = build(:user)
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: user`. Does that makes any sense ?

Comment: That looks at least like a different kind of dependency problem. Unfortunately no it is not something I am familiar with. Probably something  else that your original app or its specs do that you need to replicate in the Grape API's specs or move to your gem.

Comment: @NeilSlater you are right, this is way better but still didn't solve the main issue :) do u think I'll need to require the factories manually? or maybe I'd put them in lib/core/factories.rb, so users can just do `require core/factories` ?? what is your thought on this ?